Are visits to Schengen area already being recorded into Entry/Exit System (EES)?
https://www.euronews.com/travel/2024/07/18/new-eu-border-controls-delayed-until-end-of-2023-how-will-the-ees-affect-travellers

Entry/Exit System (EES) is expected to launch this autumn (...) the new Schengen border checks will now start on 10 November, with the possibility to postpone by a week to 17 November

Is it known if visits to Schengen area will be recorded into EES starting only in November 2024? Or have previous visits already been recorded into EES and border checks will only start using them in November 2024?

EES will have a soft launch (whatever that means) for 6 months, which would make recording pre-EES entries irrelevant for the calculation of the 90/180 rule.

@NicolasFormichella I am sorry, can you please rephrase in other words, I don't quite understand what you are explaining. Thank you

@notahamburger EES is not functional for now. Stamps are the current method of recording entries and exits, and will remain so until EES starts (at least).

According to How will EES work?  What is new during the border checks?, initial registration in EES includes fingerprinting or capture of a facial image and storage of the resulting data in the system.  This can't happen until the system is operating.
The FAQ in support of carriers (pdf) notes that the transitional period will be the six months after the beginning of operation.  It says:

The EES transition period is a period of 180 days from the date EES enters into operation according to Article
22 of Regulation (EU) 2017/2226. During this period, border authorities will verify the remaining days of
authorised stay by checking the stamps in the travel documents manually and verify and record the
entry/exit data in EES.

The answer to your question, therefore, is that visits to Schengen area will be recorded into EES starting only in November 2024, and that any information about relevant earlier visits that may be available from passport stamps will be added manually to the traveler's EES record as necessary.
